# UItableview grouped cell.image causing square corners

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using UItableview grouped and adding images to the cell using cell.imageView setImage:

When I add the image it causing the grouped table to have square corners. I am trying to duplicate the same look as the itunes iphone app which keeps the corner radius.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Notes using iphone 3.0 as base.

Thanking you in advance
Jacko

Answer (score 0):

Add a imageview ass a subview of a uiview, then add the tableview as a subview of uiview and clear the backgroundcolor of table view.

```
[myTableView setbackGroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

then it should be fine.